# PHPMailer SMTP_Connect() fail when using SMTPAuth = true

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

In PHPMailer on Godaddy Server, when I use `SMTPAuth = false`, then the script can send the mail without any issue. But If I set the value to `SMTPAuth = true`, then it cannot connect to SMTP and issue an error. The email and password are working when opening from webmail.

I'm using following code to send mail using PHPMailer:

```
    $fromEmail = ['message'=>'abc@example.com','confirm'=>'xyz@example.com'];
    if(isset($fromEmail[$purpose])) {
        $fromEmail = $fromEmail[$purpose];
    }
    else{
        $fromEmail = $fromEmail['message'];
    }
    $mail = new \PHPMailer(); // create a new object

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Host = 'a2plcpnl0721.prod.iad2.secureserver.net';
    //$mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false; //true
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Username = $fromEmail;
    $mail->Password = "1seerain";
    $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, 'InspireTrend');
    $mail->addReplyTo($fromEmail, 'InspireTrend');
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $msg;
    if($multiEmail && is_array($email)){
        foreach ($email as $key => $value) {
            $mail->clearAddresses();
            $mail->AddAddress($value);
            if(!$mail->Send()) {
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
    }
```

Is there any configuration I'm missing. Any suggestion would be appreciable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite common for ISPs own mail servers to not require authentication - you are effectively authenticated implicitly by being on their network. Trying to authenticate when the server doesn't offer authentication (especially without encryption) will likely result in an error, as you're seeing. In short, just don't use authentication, you don't need it.